# Grails when use session, how to decide choose request.getSession(true) or request.getSession(false)

Tags: unit-testing, grails

In a filter, I use request.getSession(false) to get a session, and it's ok. But when i do unit test for it, the request.getSession(false） will return null obj and test result is failed. If i want to pass the test I should use request.getSession(true)。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

request.getSession(true) creates a new session *if and only if* one does not already exist. If one already exists, like in a production environment, it uses the one available in the Java EE servlet container that called your code.

In other words, you can use request.getSession() (which is the same as getSession(true)) anywhere in the production environment that you currently use request.getSession(false). There is no need to do getSession(false) in the production environment, getSession(true) will always return the current session if one exists. In the test environment you will of course get a blank session, which you will then need to populate with whatever data is needed to run your test. But it should do the right thing in both places.

Note that Grails has its own session object that wraps the Java EE session object so you may wish to use that instead...